# How to delegate to a RestController by condition?

Tags: java, spring, spring-rest

I have several existing `@RestController`s. The path to access these controllers are eg:

```
localhost/first/test
localhost/second/test
```

code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/first")
public class MyRestController1 {
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void test(@Valid RestParameters p) {
        //...
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/second")
public class MyRestController2 {

}
```

Question: is it possible to catch a different url, and delegate to these controllers including automated validation of the `@Valid` rest parameters?

Example: `localhost?param=first`. Would it be possible to delegate this to `localhost/first/test`?

Also I want to copy the full querystring and send it to the appropriate restcontroller. The querystring will be different when accessing `/first` or `/second`, and may have different parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) 
Create a class which captures `@Path("/")`. Lets call this "Class1"

Step 2) 
Create a method within Class1, but don't change the `@Path("")` for this method. Ensure that it appropriately captures the `@QueryString("param") String firstOrLast`. Lets call this "Method1"

Step 3)
Now when you access `localhost?param=first`, `Class1.Method1()` is invoked. Therefore inside this method you can build some logic (e.g. `if (firstOrLast.equals("first")) { // call method_x }` where method_x is the relevant delegated method as you've called it.

Comment: Yes, but if I delegate to `myRestController1.test(params)` I want to ensure this get's automatically validated by `@Valid` and all the other `spring` stuff.

Comment: Are you validating the same objects for every condition in `Class1.Method1()`? If true, then you can copy / move the `@Valid` stuff to the `Class1.Method1()` prior to delegation...

Comment: No, I have different validation contraints, because the `get-query` string will differ between controllers.